# UK tax for foreign freelancer

Tags: taxes, uk, remote

I am a Vietnamese freelancer. I have UK based clients who I am doing work for whilst I was here in Vietnam (totally working remotely with 6-month contract). The earning and salary will be transferred to my Vietnamese bank account. Do I need to pay UK tax as a freelance foreigner? I am currently sifting through their website but would appreciate some immediate feedback.

Comment: No, you don't have to pay tax in the UK. I don't know the rules in Vietnam but probably you will be asked to pay tax in there. It is your client's responsibility to justify the expense.

Answer (score 0):

## You pay taxes where you live. You *do not* pay taxes where your customers/clients live.

I don't know about Vietnam, but traditionally you pay taxes where **you** live, not where clients live. You would pay Vietnamese taxes based upon your income. You would *not* pay UK taxes since you don't live in the UK.

Comment: Comments are not meant for extended arguments. If you feel the user is incorrect, use [chat]. If you feel the answer is correct, upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: Do you get a salary or to you write them invoices?

If you get a Salary, they should have to look after the formalities. Though that may be different in you country.

If you get paid on a freelancing basis, which I presume since  you posted here, you have to look after the formalities. 
If this is considered a B-to-B transaction you customer probably needs to register  and pay VAT under the reverse-charge procedure.

If you deal with private customers you´d have to register in the EU vor VAT. If you are not able to do this, there are Payment providers wich are and can invoice for you, but that will cost you a fee.

For definitiv answers pleas consult a tax adviser, as legal counseling is out of scope here.